# Calling an outside function inside a Python class

Tags: python, function, class

I'm importing another Python file into the one I'm currently writing a class in. In one of the class methods, I want to call a function that I have written in the imported Python file.

How do I go about doing this?

Comment: Can you please show us the code that you tried doing?

Comment: sure, one second. edit: it was the duplicate thing that code frenzy mentioned. thanks!

Comment: ```module.function```. http://effbot.org/zone/import-confusion.htm

Comment: So this can be closed?

Comment: I actually have this exact question and I can't find an answer or example of it elsewhere - the linked question only tells how to import outside functions, but I want to properly import an outside function into a class.  Question forthcoming...